# Deploy WebSocket Sharp Application

Tags: .net, sockets, iis, websocket, lan

I have written an server application with [WebSocket Sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp)
and now I want to access the Server from Client other than localhost.

But the Server doesn´t answer, the client connects neither.
How do I host my SocketServer?

My Client looks like:

```
        using (var ws = new WebSocket("ws://169.168.1.5:8080/Service"))
        {
            ws.OnOpen += (sender, e) =>
                Console.WriteLine("Connect");

            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Response from Server");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            };

            ws.Connect();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();

                ws.SendAsync("Test", null);
            }
        }
```

My Server in short:

```
        // build socket-server
        var httpSocketServer = new HttpServer(8080);

        // add service  with route + start
        httpSocketServer.AddWebSocketService<MessageReceiver>("/Service");
        httpSocketServer.Start();

        // wait for operations
        while (true) ;
```

Comment: Have you added exceptions to Windows Firewall?

Comment: to server: yes to client: no